# variables overwrite themselves when going through the loop

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create some code that searches a word for references in a dictionary however after finding its first word it overwrites itself when going through the loop again.

I've tried making all the variables that have values stored in them  into arrays however when i do this i get a tone of object reference errors.

```
  For x = 0 To 58110
        For i = 0 To 58110
            mypos(i) = 1
            mypos(i) = InStr(password, dictionary_english(i))
            If mypos(i) > 0 Then

                word1 = dictionary_english(i)
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(word1) Then found_word = True
                MsgBox(mypos(i))
                MsgBox(word1)
                If found_word = True Then
                    mylengthpassword = Len(password)
                    mylengthdictionary = Len(word1)
                    Dim secstr As String
                    Dim finalstr As String
                    Dim befstr As String
                    secstr = password.Substring(mypos(i) - 1)
                    finalstr = secstr.Substring(mylengthdictionary)
                    befstr = Mid(password, 1, mypos(i) - 1)
                    MsgBox(word1)
                    MsgBox(secstr)
                    MsgBox(word1)
                    MsgBox(password)
                    MsgBox(befstr)

                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

I want is so that all founded words are stored into a list or array of some sort with there position where they were found.

Comment: If you want to keep things in a list, use a List<T>.

Comment: (1) I notice that you aren't using `x`, so you could remove that particular For loop. (2) You've forgotten to set `found_word = False` anywhere inside the loop - you could solve that by using `found_word = Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(word1)`.

Comment: If you are trying to create a password that isn't in the dictionary that does not make it safe. Don't try to create your own encryption just use a hash and salt created by experts in this specialized field. BCrypt seems popular now and is available for .net in a Nuget package.

Comment: Try to use .net methods directly instead of old VB6 methods which will call the .net methods internally. Will save time in a loop that executes over 3 billion times. Refering to Mid, Len and InStr

Comment: Don't use MsgBox to debug code. If you don't want to use Visual Studio's excellent debugger, at least do Debug.Print. Results in Immediate window. Inevitably you will forget to remove the MsgBox. Been there, done that, they repossessed my T shirt.

Comment: I'm not trying to make my own encription I'm just trying to check a password strength. However In this one part of one of my checks the variables overwrite and I cant find a way around it.

Comment: @LarsTech told you how in the very first comment.

Comment: Is 58,110 the number of words in the English dictionary?

Comment: Yes theres 58110 words in the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot quite get a handle on what check you are doing. This is as close as I could come. The English dictionary could just as easily be an array.

```
Private dictionary_english As New List(Of String)

Private Function CheckStrength(password As String) As String
    For Each word In dictionary_english
        If word.Contains(password) Then
            Return "Password contained in Dictionary"
            'The function will stop checking as soon as it finds a match
        End If
    Next
    Return "Password is not found in dictionary"
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim message = CheckStrength(txtPassword.Text)
    MessageBox.Show(message)
End Sub
```

Comment: This way sounds great it's just that how would I make it so it doesnt stop after finding the first match and still checks the whole ditionary for references of other words.

Comment: Your code didn't seem to counting the number of times a match was found or saving the words where it was found. What is it that you want to know about matches?

Comment: I figured it out thanks for your help a lot. Added a couple of lines to your code.